# Force insert statement in sqlalchemy to use quotes around all columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a parameter in sqlalchemy when doing an insert using the ORM that you can force the python library to quote all columns?

For example,

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_A.SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A (date, col1, "col 2") values (:data1, :data2, :data3)
```

is the statement that is currently generated if I am using a pandas dataframe with columns `date`, `col1` and `col 2`.  Note, `col 2` is quoted due to the space already.  However, I would like to go ahead and quote `date` and `col1` because in my database date is a reserved word and needs to be quoted.

Is there an engine or dialect parameter that will enable quote of all columns such that the generated insert statement will result in:

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_A.SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A ("date", "col1", "col 2") values (:data1, :data2, :data3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a reserved word isn't being quoted, this is a bug in the dialect that should be fixed. Pending a fix, the dialect's reserved words can be extended like this in most cases*:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(url)
engine.dialect.preparer.reserved_words.add('date')
```

If you really want to quote all column names, you can use a [custom compilation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/compiler.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.compiler):

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateColumn
from sqlalchemy.sql.elements import quoted_name

@compiles(CreateColumn)
def my_column(element, compiler, **kw):
    column = element.element
    if not isinstance(column.name, quoted_name) or column.name.quote is None:
        column.name = quoted_name(column.name, True)
    return compiler.visit_create_column(element, **kw)
```

Finally, for invidual columns you can pass `quote=True` to the constructor,

```py
tbl = sa.Table(
          't', 
          sa.MetaData(), 
          sa.Column('c', sa.Date, quote=True)
)
```

but this approach doesn't scale, and assumes that you have control of the column definitions which may not be the case when using Pandas or similar.

---

* MySQL and MariaDB have separate reserved words sets in SQLAlchemy; if using MariaDB you may need to find and extend the MariaDB reserved word set specifically by adding to `sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.reserved_words. RESERVED_WORDS_MARIADB`.